# how to load panorama item when it is opnened

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, panorama-control

in my wp8 app I create loaded event for all of the panoramma items but when i run app all of the panorama items are loaded immediately but i want them to be loaded when i flick to the panorama item

```
private void podne_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tesbihat2.Content = TextToXaml("podne.txt");
}

private void ikindi_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tesbihat3.Content = TextToXaml("ikindi.txt");
}

private void aksam_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tesbihat4.Content = TextToXaml("aksam.txt");
}

private void jacija_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    tesbihat5.Content = TextToXaml("jacija.txt");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void Panorama_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (((Panorama)sender).SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0: // defines the first PanoramaItem Loaded
            MessageBox.Show("First Item is on ForeGround");
            break;
        case 1: // second one
            MessageBox.Show("Second Item is on ForeGround");
            break;

        case 2: // third one
            MessageBox.Show("Third Item is on ForeGround");
            break;
    }
}
```